# Phonegap-nfc plugin causes build to fail on xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, phonegap, capacitor

I am using ionic 5 capacitor and i am trying to get phonegap-nfc plugin to work. It works fine on android but while building with xcode building fails.

Steps to reproduce with fresh project (selected Angular framework when it was asked):

```
ionic start myApp blank --capacitor
cd myApp
ionic build
ionic capacitor add ios
npx cap open ios
```

It opens in xcode and i can build and run project on simulator just fine. Then i install phonegap-nfc plugin:

```
npm install phonegap-nfc
npm install @ionic-native/nfc
ionic cap sync
```

When i try to build again i receive semantic issue with cordovaplugins. There are 5 errors in NfcPlugin.m file saying **'new' is unavailable** with note saying **'init has been explicitly marked unavailable here**. How to fix this issue?

Some version info of my system:
Xcode version: 12.5 (12E262)
macOS version: Big Sur 11.3
node version: 16.0.0 (also tried with 10.16.0)
npm version: 7.10.0

[Screenshot of xcode errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZNKz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question as i happened to find solution. I dont what is broken in xcode 12.5, but uninstalling xcode 12.5 and installing xcode 11.7 i was able to build succesfully and scan NFC tags.

Comment: please don't mark this as solved, I would like to know why this is broken as I am having the same issue!

Comment: I wont mark it as solved because it is more like workaround than actual solution. I got it working with xcode 12.2 too. I think for new ios apps xcode 12.x is needed for publishing app to store. I havent tried other version between 12.2 and 12.5.

Comment: @KrishanPatel have look at https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/pull/451/commits/0c1b3c09d6f056e5f4a2124e6cbc7a50ee935436. You just have to replace new with alloc